# Generate java classes from WSDL through java program

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, wsdl2java

I used wsimport command line tool for creating classses but I want to do it from the java code. Any idea?

Comment: Could you say why do you need this?

Comment: cause I need to make dynamic service invoker based on the WSDL. So I need dynamic creating of web service classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to call the `WsImport` `main()` method:

```
import com.sun.tools.ws.WsImport;

...

String[] args = {"put", "your", "arguments", "here"};
WsImport.main(args);
```

I think that this is what the [Ant task](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/wsimport.html#Ant_task) does.

---

**Update:** I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to do (and I don't think that you want to generate source code and compile it during runtime).

If the question is actually about doing dynamic invocation, JAX-WS's dynamic invocation interface (DII) is the `javax.xml.ws.Dispatch` object. Check [JAX-WS's dynamic Dispatch interface](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-jaxwsrpc4/#N10100).

Comment: I've been trying to understand what he's trying to do for a while, and I finally I came to the conclusion that he wants something like http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [wsimport ant task](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/wsimport.html#Ant_task) programatically.

You can do this by using the task class - `com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport`. Instantiate it, set its properties (as defined on the task documentation), and call the `execute()` method.

Comment: I cant see how I can execute wsimport from java

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not typical Java Web Services flow. But you can achieve this with dynamic JVM based [Groovy language](http://groovy.codehaus.org) using [GroovyWS](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS) module.